# Callable functions result in {"verifications":{"app":"MISSING","auth":"MISSING"}

Tags: firebase, flutter

When I try to call a function via the flutter SDK, it results in the following error the firebase end.

```json
 {"verifications":{"app":"MISSING","auth":"MISSING"},"logging.googleapis.com/labels":{"firebase-log-type":"callable-request-verification"},"severity":"INFO","message":"Callable request verification passed"}
```

I am testing on the Firebase Emulator. I do not have the AppCheck plugin installed.The `cloud_functions` plugin version is 3.2.1

The code for the call is:

```
final callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('create_source');

final resp = await callable.call(accountData);
```

I am following the setup docs. What am I doing

Answer (score 2):

According to a GitHub-issue-report this message is displayed when testing with the emulator. The regular security checks are bypassed and the message is logged to inform the user about this fact ("severity":"INFO").

See [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4259#issuecomment-1060979596) for original GitHub answer.